# Chef - multiple files dynamic template resource

Tags: chef, dynamic, template

I'm trying to find a way to apply template resource dynamically on all files which are in a folder inside the cookbook's template folder. something like:

```
Dir.foreach("../templates/default/shared/") do | file | # This is the wrong line...
  template "/home/admin/shared/#{file}" do
    source "shared/#{file}"
    …
  end
end
```

how can I do it? I'm trying to avoid having a separate list of all the files in this directory as a variable...
thanks.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/522671/how-to-use-current-cookbook-template-dir-to-copy-all-templates-recursively-in-a/722533#722533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will be executed in the context of a node, so your Ruby code (`Dir.foreach`) will need to examine the node's local cache. In my Chef installation, the local cache path is required for my chef-client configuration template, so I have this attribute: `node[:chef][:cache_path]`.

So:

```
Dir.foreach("#{node[:chef][:cache_path]}/cookbooks/the_cookbook/templates/default/shared/")
```

EDIT:
In modern Chef configurations, templates won't exist on the server until they're needed.  You'll need to add this to your [client.rb](https://docs.getchef.com/config_rb_client.html):

```
no_lazy_load true
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I thought about it, but didn't know how much can I rely on this cache or how do I get to it. So, what should I do to have this attribute too? it's not there by default if I got you right.

Comment: Check your cookbooks and attributes. The cache was there for me by default in the "chef" cookbook, because it was required to configure the chef configuration template.

Comment: In the current version of Chef, it looks like the templates aren't locally downloaded until you explicitly require them... so the template dir on the server will be empty when you start.  Chicken/Egg